# Message 400 in Postman for POST request

Tags: spring-boot, postman

I am devloping REST api for file upload using spring boot. For testing, I have installed postman plugin in Chrome. For file upload, I got below message,

{"status": 400,"message": "For input string: \"ABS片仮名; カタカナ\""}

Excel sheet i am uploading. In that excel sheet one column has combined English and Japanese letters.
Database i need to load is mysql and that particular column is defined as VARCHAR(500). 
Please assist me on this. Thanks.

Comment: Please post your code, how can we know what is wrong without the code?

Comment: Post your controller endpoint

Comment: endpoint:  localhost:7080/fileUpload/reference

Comment: I cannot paste the code completely, here is the code which i hope is the root cause,   Reference ref = new Reference();  ref.setErrorMessage(getStringVaue(currentRow.getCell(12)));

Comment: data is : ｴｷｿﾞｰｽﾄﾊﾞﾙﾌﾞ脱落

Comment: does anybody have the solution ?, i am able to push the same data in mysql table, but postman apps throwing 'message 400' when submitting as "POST" request during file upload.